# Knit doesn't find dataset

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, render

I'm using R and I am trying to render a Rmd file using Knit button. I built a 
S3 function

```
readprices.numeric<-function(y){
library(readr)
dat<-read_csv(file="data/EuStockMarkets.csv")
}
```

However, Knit tells me that "data/EuStockMarkets.csv" doesn't exist in current work directory, despite the fact that on the console the function works. 
How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: what is the result of `getwd()`, and does `./data/EuStockMarkets.csv` exist under it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the working directory:

```
setwd("absolute/path/directory")
```

Let us know if that works.